# Why can't I use $v=\sqrt{\frac{2E_{k}}{m}}$ to calculate for velocity instead of having to use $v=\sqrt{2gh}$?

Tags: energy

[image]

In this problem, $KE=980$ J and $m=20 $ kg. Why must I use $v=\sqrt{2gh} $ instead of $v=\sqrt{\frac{2KE}{m}}$?

Comment: Both formulas give the exact same result and are in fact identical if you plug in your expression for KE.

Comment: Did I substitute something incorrectly, as $\sqrt{980} \neq \sqrt{98}$?

Comment: $E_k$ should be $9800$ J not $980$ J.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't see the extra 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given $m$ and $h$ so to find the kinetic energy at the bottom of the hill you have to use $E_k = mgh$. You can do two steps:

$E_k = mgh\\ \displaystyle v=\sqrt{\frac {2E_k}m}$

or you can just do one step:

$v = \sqrt {2gh}$